# Sqlite returns no result for select * in one function and a result in another function

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqlite

today I ran twice over a very strange issue.

I have two functions, which are using in this example the same SQL Statement. *getOrderOverview()* returns rows, *getDetailsOrder()* not.

I can't figure out why. I am using SQLite and a ASP.NET application with C#. What makes it even more strange is, if I copy the function and rename it, the SQL statement works again. Does anyone know where this behavior comes from?

```
public List<Dictionary<string, string>> getOrderOverview(int status)
    {
        string sql = "SELECT * FROM bestellung";

        using (SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, m_dbConnection))
        {
            using (SQLiteDataReader r = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (r.Read())
                {
                    ...
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public order getDetailsOrder(string orderId)
    {
        string sql = "SELECT * FROM bestellung";

        using (SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, m_dbConnection))
        {
            using (SQLiteDataReader r = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (r.Read())
                {
                    ...
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Clearly, you're leaving out the code that makes the difference. Look over your code again. Find the parts that are clearly different, but "they couldn't possibly matter". The problem is in one of those. You didn't say how you determined that the query's returning no rows, so my first guess is that it's behaving identically but you're doing something different in one of the `Read()` loops. Or maybe you've got an overload of one of these methods, and you're not calling the actual method you think you are.

Comment: But including *only the code that's identical between the two cases" is guaranteed to be a waste of time. If they're different, it's the differences that make them not the same.

Comment: Durring debugging I am looking in the r variable, after the ExecuteReader() command is done. 
The other code, that makes the functions different is in the while loop. In my original function, the SQL Statement is way more complex and was giving me an error. So I reduced the statement, till I came back to SELECT * FROM bestellung and even this Statement wasn't working in the function. This left me confused, because a 2nd function is using exact this statement and is working.

Comment: And you've confirmed that `m_dbConnection` is identical in both cases, is connected to the same DB instance, etc.?